# Javascript and HTML onclick event- how to disable and add

Tags: javascript, html, click

As an experiment for a larger project, I am trying to make a text battle (it's in progress). What I need is when I press the button, it prints the text into a `<p>` tag. Also, it makes two buttons, one that says ATTACK and the other says SPARE. How would I

1. disable the initial onclick event from the button so I don't keep on making new buttons
2. add an onclick event to the new ones so I could run a different function.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
  <button id = 'button' onclick='enemy()'>button</button>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
    // PLAYER
var playerHP = 100;
var playerAt = 10;
var playerDef = 0;
//ENEMY
var enemyHP = 50;
var enemyAt = 5;
//FIGHT
function enemy() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "You encounter a wild MONSTER(AT:5 ¦ HP:50). Will you attack?";

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    var btnAt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var t = document.createTextNode('Attack!');
    btnAt.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btnAt);

    var btnSp = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var d = document.createTextNode('Spare!');
    btnSp.appendChild(d);
    document.body.appendChild(btnSp);
    }

}
```

Ignore some of the stuff- its for future use.

P.S. No jQuery, please, unless it is unavoidable.

Comment: If you want some stuff to be ignored, remove it then.

Comment: jQuery is never unavoidable -- In fact, it's easier to avoid it than not.

Answer (score 0):

something like this using .Disabled to disable the button, so you dont have to clear out the onclick for later use. and just set .onclick to whatever function you want on the button you built. I also recommend not trying to avoid jquery... Once you start using it, you can relize how much easier it can make your life. Also, why the loop?

```
// PLAYER
var playerHP = 100;
var playerAt = 10;
var playerDef = 0;
//ENEMY
var enemyHP = 50;
var enemyAt = 5;
//FIGHT
function enemy() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "You encounter a wild MONSTER(AT:5 ¦ HP:50). Will you attack?";


    var btnAt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    //set onlick for button
    btnAt.onclick = function()
    {
     //do stuff here
    }
    var t = document.createTextNode('Attack!');
    btnAt.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btnAt);

    var btnSp = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var d = document.createTextNode('Spare!');
    btnSp.appendChild(d);
    document.body.appendChild(btnSp);

    //disable button
    var originalbtn = document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
}
```